# segfault when accessing function in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, gdb, function-pointers

I am trying to implement sets on top of red-black trees. My trees are defined with the following struct:

```
typedef struct rb_tree {
int (*compare)(const void* a, const void* b); 
void (*destroy_key)(void* a);
void (*destroy_info)(void* a);
void (*print_key)(const void* a);
void (*print_info)(void* a);
rb_node* root;             
rb_node* nil;              
} rb_tree;
```

Whenever I try to access the compare function I get a segfault. e.g in the comparisons in the if statements in this helper function:

```
void tree_insert_help(rb_tree* tree, rb_node* z) {
rb_node* x;
rb_node* y;
rb_node* nil = tree->nil;

z->left = z->right = nil;
y = tree->root;
x = tree->root->left;
while( x !=  nil) {
    y = x;
    if (1 == tree->compare(x->key, z->key)) { /* x.key > z.key */ 
        x = x->left;
    } else { /* x,key < =  z.key  */
        x = x->right;
    }
}
z->parent = y;
if ( (y == tree->root) || (1 == tree->compare(y->key, z->key))) { /* y.key > z.key */
    y->left = z;
} else {
    y->right = z;
} 
}
```

This is the code that I am using to test and am getting the segfault from. Note that I have

```
typedef struct rb_tree *set; 
typedef struct rb_node *element;
```

in set.h

```
#include "set.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {;

int int_comp(const void* a,const void* b) {
  if( *(int*)a > *(int*)b) return(1);
  if( *(int*)a < *(int*)b) return(-1);
  return(0);
}
    void dfunc(void * a){
        free((int*)a);
    }
    void dinfo(void* a){
        ;
    }
    void print_int(int* a){
        printf("%d",*a);
    }
    set seta = new_set(int_comp, dfunc, dinfo, print_int, null_function);
    int x = 10;
    int y = 9;
    int z = 12;
    insert_element(seta, &x);
    insert_element(seta, &y);
    insert_element(seta, &z);
    print_set(seta);
}
```

This code fails on the second insert, since it calls tree->compare. Using GDB to do a stack trace I get the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffffffde1b8 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffffffde1b8 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000400ce1 in TreeInsertHelp (tree=0x604010, z=0x604360) at red_black_tree.c:185
#2  0x0000000000400dce in RBTreeInsert (tree=0x604010, key=0x7ffffffde160, info=0x604340) at red_black_tree.c:233
#3  0x000000000040096b in insert_element (seta=0x604010, key=0x7ffffffde160) at set.c:22
#4  0x0000000000400848 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffffffde2c8) at test.c:38
```

Furthermore, this actually runs completely fine in valgrind. This is the first time I have used functions in structs in c. I have tried to lookup this issue elsewhere and have made little progress debugging it. Why would I get a segfault when I try to access the compare function in the tree struct?

EDIT:
New set is a wrapper for the following function which creates a new tree.

```
rb_tree* rb_tree_create( int (*comp_func) (const void*, const void*),
                void (*dest_func) (void*),
                void (*info_dest_func) (void*),
                void (*print_func) (const void*),
                void (*print_info)(void*)) {
rb_tree* new_tree;
rb_node* temp;

new_tree = (rb_tree*) safe_malloc(sizeof(rb_tree));
new_tree->compare = comp_func;
new_tree->destroy_key = dest_func;
new_tree->print_key = print_func;
new_tree->print_info = print_info;
new_tree->destroy_info = info_dest_func;

temp = (rb_node*) safe_malloc(sizeof(rb_node));
new_tree->nil = temp;
temp->parent = temp;
temp->left = temp;
temp->right = temp;
temp->red = 0;
temp->key = 0;
temp = (rb_node*) safe_malloc(sizeof(rb_node));
new_tree->root = temp;
temp->parent = new_tree->nil;
temp->left = new_tree->nil;
temp->right = new_tree->nil;
temp->key = 0;
temp->red = 0;
return(new_tree); 
}
```

EDIT 2:
I resolved my problem. The functions which I was passing the pointers of to new_set were defined within the main function. When I moved them outside the the main function it stopped segfaulting.

Comment: `new_set` show that. Also this is not [mcve]

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. Doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely both that users will up-vote your posts and that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't really matter which style your choose (although, for some languages, some styles are more appropriate than others). But, *pick one* and *use it consistently* for all code in a single project.

Answer (score 1):

You've created a struct, "compare" is a pointer to function. But it's pointing nowhere. 
It should be set in your "new_set" function, but you didn't show it.

In your "new_set" function you should do something like this:

```
... // new_set_struct is a struct that you've created and returning from new_set function
new_set_struct->compare = &int_comp;
... // all other new_set_struct initial configuration is following
return new_set_struct;
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have thought to include new_set in the question. When I am setting pointers to functions do I need to use &? I was under the impression that for functions the following were equivalent:  new_set_struct->compare = &int_comp;, and   new_set_struct->compare = int_comp;

Comment: @user3210228.: Yes they are equivalent.